# self-centralizers in p-groups

Tags: finite-groups, gr.group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $P$ a $p$-group.

(1) If $A$ is a *maximal* Abelian subgroup, what are nice examples where it isn't self-centralizing?

(2) What if $A$ happens to be normal as well?

Comment: A maximal abelian subgroup is always self-centralising: $A$ and an element from the centraliser generate an abelian subgroup.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If $A$ is maximal abelian subgroup, it must be self-centralizing. Otherwise you can add to $A$ an element from $Cent_G(A)$ and get a bigger abelian subgroup.

Comment: Ah, great - this seems simple then. IS this types of thing in any group theory book?

Comment: Let me add to the comments of Torsten and Yiftach that the converse is also true, i.e. in every (either finite or infinite) group the self-centralizing subgroups are exactly the maximal abelian subgroups. 

Comment: @Ralph What do you mean? Every abelian subgroup centralises itself, maximal or not.

Comment: This is not a research level question: I think it is better to close it.

Comment: Alex, a subgroup A of a group is said to be self-centralizing if $A$ coincides with its centraliser in G. Thus, what affirmed by Ralph is correct. 

Comment: @Salvo: Thanks, for confirming. @Alex: Let $H \le G$ with $H=C_G(H)$ where  $C_G(H) := \{g \in G \mid \forall h \in H: gh=hg\}$. Since $H\le C_G(H)$, $H$ is abelian. Assume $H$ is not max. abelian. Then there is an abelian $A \varsupsetneqq H$. It follows $A \le C_G(H) =H$ which is impossible. Thus $H$ is max. abelian. qed. 

Comment: In addition, in a finite nilpotent group, every maximal *normal* abelian subgroup is self-centralizing. This is probably in any finite group theory book, for example in Isaacs, Lemma 4.16.